# Have multiple directories in processing when using the processing-ide?

Tags: processing, project-structure, processing-ide

I currently began a new project with processing and first started with the 
processing-ide that comes together with the installation. 
Is it possible to structure the project into subdirectories instead of having to put all classes into the single sketch folder? I looked at the documentation at https://processing.org/ but didn't find any useful information about how to divide projects into manageable source subdirectories. Your help is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No the default Processing IDE does not support this.

Before switching to another IDE for Processing, keep in mind that Processing 3 will highly focus on creating an entirely new IDE, which "might" add this functionality.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer :), still a little bit of a disappointment though...

Comment: @ketbra You should try eclipse with the Proclipsing plugin